# Find function end address

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, disassembly, machine-code

I'm creating a small program to obfuscate others programs in C++, I need to find the address where the function ends, for example:

```
55                    - push ebp
8B EC                 - mov ebp,esp
83 EC 24              - sub esp,24
85 D2                 - test edx,edx
74 2B                 - je 0006111F
66 83 3A 00           - cmp word ptr [edx],0
74 25                 - je 0006111F
83 65 DC 00           - and dword ptr [ebp-24],0
57                    - push edi
6A 08                 - push 8
59                    - pop ecx
33 C0                 - xor eax,eax
8D 7D E0              - lea edi,[ebp-20]
F3 AB                 - repe stosd 
8D 45 DC              - lea eax,[ebp-24]
50                    - push eax
6A 00                 - push 0
52                    - push edx
FF 15 48100700        - call dword ptr [00071048]
F7 D8                 - neg eax
1B C0                 - sbb eax,eax
F7 D8                 - neg eax
5F                    - pop edi
C9                    - leave 
C3                    - ret
```

I need to find where the function ends, in this case `C3                    - ret`

This is my current code:

```
uint8_t* find_function_end(uint8_t* function)
{
    while (true)
    {
        auto opcode_size = x86disassembler::opcode_size(function);

        //  Failed to get opcode size
        if (!opcode_size)
            return nullptr;

        //  Search for the following opcodes:
        //  C3          - ret
        //  CB          - ret
        //  C2 iw       - ret imm16
        //  CA iw       - ret imm16
        if ((*function == 0xC3 || *function == 0xCB) && opcode_size == 1 ||
            (*function == 0xC2 || *function == 0xCA) && opcode_size == 3)
            return function;

        function += opcode_size;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

The problem is, some functions doesn't end with ret opcode 
or some functions has two or more returns, how to get it in an effective way?

Comment: Not really helpful, but checking for `ret` can give false positives as branching could lead to a function having multiple points of return and multiple `ret` instructions.

Comment: Yes, it's not the most effective way, but I have nothing else in mind, I need some more effective idea, I forgot to mention this problem in the post, I will edit, thank you.

Comment: Also not very helpful, but in a stream of instructions, there's really no clear beginning or end to "functions". The closest you could get is probably to find all `call` instructions, and keep a table of the destinations of those `call` instructions. With that you could *guess* where functions begins and ends (the instruction before the target of a `call`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: In compiler-generated code, there are functions.  But they can end with a tailcall `jmp` to another function instead of `call`/`ret`.  The OP says they're obfuscating other C++ programs, so they could compile with debug symbols available to make it easy to find the *start* of every function.  **ELF metadata can also contain `.size` for every symbol, and compilers do generate that**.  So I'd look at that instead of the instruction stream.  You could look for `call` targets, but there are callback functions, and only-tailcalled functions.

Comment: Current compilers typically miss the optimization of making conditional tailcalls with `jcc rel32`, instead doing a `jcc` over a `jmp` or something stupid like that.  So seeing a `jcc` to an address lets you rule that out as a function-start if you were considering it as a tailcalled function based on `jmp` instructions.  Unless the code is hand-written, especially if it's intentionally obfuscated.

Comment: The idea of ​​using pdb would be interesting, but in some cases the pdb will not be available, for example, if the programmer compiles your project without /DEBUG or /DEBUG:FASTLINK or /DEBUG:FULL, the 
pdb will not be generated.

Comment: in addition to first `ret`, you also have to find `ret` from target (conditional) jump.

Comment: Generically speaking this is NP problem, so I don't think you can build foolproof system if you will only depend on code itself. You probably need some compiler output (like debug or asm) information to solve it.

Comment: no reason to assume that compiled code is in a single chunk of machine code and ends at the end of said chunk.  also no reason to assume that the code for a function ends in a return.  the question is why are you trying to find and define the boundaries for a function blob, perhaps the real task can be done in some other way.  you could compile to object just the function itself as a standalone compile, one function per compile.  it doesnt necessarily create all the code for that function but is easier to find the boundary of what is produced.

Comment: I think it would be possible, some disassemblers like IDA(Hex Rays) can perfectly find the end of the function just by analyzing instructions.

Comment: @cYeR ad IDA/etc: they don't find it "perfectly", they have just good heuristic tuned by decades of experience (which can be still fooled). This is just "halting problem" in disguise - you want to find all possible exit paths to figure out memory layout of code (btw what about situations when other function is laying in between two parts of bigger function) = same problem in principle as trying to tell if particular code will ever stop => NP problem. Actually if you are mischievous enough, you can easily create overlapping machine code with hand assembly, making this unsolvable completely.

Comment: I mean machine code, which does provide one function when called from one entry point, and other function when called from second entry point, which points inside of some instruction of original case, for example on x86_32 `mov eax,0xc031AABB` `ret` will assemble to machine code `B8BBAA31C0C3` and if you call it from +3 offset, it will do `xor eax,eax ret` instead... if the original code uses this as obfuscation and knows the call at offset loads bottom 16b of eax with 0xAABB and the +3 call clears it, it will confuse output of many disassemblers, but also it's not clear what your SW would do.